# Embark build gives error "Couldn't connect to an Ethereum node are you sure it's on?"

Tags: go-ethereum, geth, embark

I'm running embark on embark_demo project. `embark blockchain` / `geth` works fine & it says "account funded" but when I run `embark build` / `embark run` it cannot seem to find the ethereum node.

Further it points some error at: 

`Error: error connecting to blockchain node
    at Error (native)
    at checkWeb3IsConnected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/contracts/deploy_manager.js:44:27)`

[image: embark blockchain]

[image: geth command]

[image: Embark run gives this error]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if embark build starts a node, you mite want to try one window:

```
embark simulator
```

To start/stop the node, and in another window:

```
embark run
```

Oh get creative and run them together in same window using the & symbol, and piping | to grep to only show lines with a :

```
embark simulator | grep : & ; embark run
```

But then you gotta do

```
killall node
```

to stop the node cos it's in background.